Help identifying a late 70s/early 80s android made-for-TV movie
This one has been bothering me for years.  I believe it was the very early 80s (but could be late 70s) because it's in my memory along with This House Possessed, which took me a long time to find.
My memory says it was set in modern day and was not futuristic, there was also no space travel involved. The plot line revolved around a couple (although they met up with or made a male friend during the movie) that were traveling away from their home.
They wound up discovering that there was a factory that was making a cyborg/android duplicate of each human.  It was then the duplicate's task to kill their human duplicate, so they could replace them.  The friend winds up getting killed by his duplicate and the couple gets separated and each has to battle their own duplicate.
At the end of the movie the couple meets up at their home and have to test one another to determine if the other is the original human or the replacement.  I feel like they are convinced that they are both still human, but the final scene either hints at or revels that one was a duplicate.
It was most like a made-for-TV movie of that era. I was very young when I watched this so memories are not extremely clear, but it has left trauma that last until this day.

This sounds a lot like Futureworld, the 1976 sequel to the original 1973 Westworld.  From Wikipedia:

The trio decides to flee the resort on the next plane. The reporters
return to their apartment where Duffy is waiting for them; he explains
that, by cloning world leaders, they can ensure that nothing harms
Delos' interests, and that without "proper" guidance, humans will
eventually destroy the planet. Cloning the reporters would ensure
favorable coverage, letting people forget about the Westworld tragedy.
Browning attacks Duffy but is easily overpowered by Duffy's unnatural
strength. Ballard shoots the doctor twice, and Browning peels back
Duffy's face to reveal that he is a robot.
As Harry races to meet up with the reporters, he runs into Browning's
clone, who kills him. Ballard and Browning are then chased by their
own duplicates, all the while taunting them with details about their
lives. Eventually, one of each pair is killed, though which one is
left unclear. When they find each other, Browning seizes and kisses
Ballard.
In the end, as they leave the resort with the other guests, Dr.
Schneider meets them to make sure they are the clones. The reporters
confirm that they will be writing positive reviews for Delos, but,
just as they reach the exit, Ballard's badly injured clone stumbles
towards him and Schneider realizes too late that he has been fooled.
On the jetway, Browning tells Ballard that his editor is running the
exposé on Delos, that the whole world will know what they are up to,
and that kissing her was his idea to figure out whether or not she was
a duplicate.

Here's the original theatrical trailer:




Thank you!  I just rewatched and that is absolutely the movie I was thinking of. Although I was wrong about the ending, the rest of my memories were pretty accurate for something I watched nearly 50 years ago.  76?  I was younger than I thought when I saw it, no wonder it's always traumatized me.

It's a bad movie, but of some interest since a lot of it was filmed at Johnson Space Center when they didn't have much going on in the mid 70s, even using the Apollo control rooms. Some was also filmed in the then-new Houston airport with the "high-tech" automated trains.
